# Can't access my React App on Google Compute Engine

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, network-programming, google-compute-engine

I'm working on a webapp in ReactJS and I have to deploy it on Google Compute Engine. Here's my problem, when I connect to my instance and `git clone` my app, I do `npm i` `npm run build` and finally `serve -s build`. It's tell me that my app is served on `10.132.0.4:5000` (`10.132.0.4` is the private IP of my VM) but when I go to `my-public-IP:5000` with my browser, it loads for a while before to say me: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. I can't figure why, I can ping my-public-IP but if I try to telnet it on port 5000, it fails. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Take a look at the [Firewall Rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) in the GCP. Make sure that you allow ingress traffic for the ports 80, 443 and 5000.
- Eventually, try to test the URL connection and the ports within the GCE VM instance, or outside the GCP. For instance,

  `$ curl http://[external-IP-vm-address]:5000`

  `$ telnet localhost 5000`

  `$ nmap <external-ip-vm-address>`

  `$ netstat -plant`
- There are other network tests that you could perform. You may consult this [discussion thread](https://superuser.com/questions/621870/test-if-a-port-on-a-remote-system-is-reachable-without-telnet) from Stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Mahmoud Sharif thanks for your response :), I make a Firewall rule who allow `tcp` traffic on port `80`, `5000` for IPs `0.0.0.0/0` and now it's working. Why do you tell me to open the port 443 ?

Comment: It is not mandatory to open the port 443. This is just in case you are using https://, if you would like to connect through SSL. If you would like to do it in the future, then you would have to open that port. If not, then it's not necessary to open it.